# Diff similar lines

Tags: grep, diff, tr, comm

I'd like to print a list of lines where the first word in two files is identical, and the rest of the words are not. Some complicated mess with `comm`, `grep` and `cut` would be possible, but hopefully there's a simpler way.

**Edit**: I've managed to slap together some [working code](https://github.com/l0b0/difff). Example tests:

```
$ cat file1
a 1 E
b 2 F
c 3 G

$ cat file2
a M X
b 2 Y
c 3 G

$ difff 1 file1 file2 # Differences in fields 2+3
1,2c1,2
< a 1 E
< b 2 F
---
> a M X
> b 2 Y

$ difff 1-2 file1 file2 # Differences in field 3 only
1c1
< b 2 F
---
> b 2 Y
```

**Edit 2**: The speed is now bearable (compares two files of 1800 and 8700 lines in half a second).

Comment: Is there some reason why a traditional (or unified) diff won't do the job?

Comment: Are the first columns of file1 and file2 identical? Have you considered `join` and `paste`? (I'm not going to offer more precise suggestion because I don't understand the requirements.)

Comment: @draeath: Because if would also show lines which start with *different* words. That's what I want to exclude. As you can see from the diff above, the lines starting with `baz` and `bay` are not included, even though they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both `file1` and `file2` are sorted (otherwise `join` won't work):

```
diff -u file1 file2 |
  grep -E "^[+-]($(echo $(join -o0 file1 file2) | tr ' ' '|'))"
```

Explanation:

The `join` command will output the join field that occurs in both files (i.e. the first word of the line which is the same in both files), one on each line. We `echo` this though `tr`, replacing all spaces with a pipe (`|`). The reason for doing the slightly convoluted `echo` (and not just piping the result from `join` directly through `tr`) is that the output from `join` will have a newline at the end of it which we do *not* want to replace with a pipe.

For the example files (*the ones that were originally given by the OP before his edit of the question*), the `join`, `echo`, `tr` thingy will produce `bar|foo`. This is the used as part of an extended regular expression in `grep -E` to filter through the output of `diff -u`.

The output of the command line is:

```
-bar c d
+bar x y
```

Comment: Didn't use `join`, but your answer pointed in the right direction.